# ways to invoke Unix shell scripts (".", "source")

Tags: bash, unix

To activate a TurboGears virtualenv (just as an example), you do this:

```
. bin/activate
```

Or this:

```
source bin/activate
```

1. Why does the current directory "." work as a command?
2. Why use "source" or "." at all?  Why not simply "bin/activate"?

(I did a little Web searching on this, but "." and "source" get a lot of bad hits.)

Comment: Hmm...I asked a specific technical question about a standard programming tool.  The question quotes code, and the responses also  quote code.  I've been studying the FAQ, and I don't understand: in what way is the question off topic?  Would it fit better in the Server Fault or Unix forum?

Comment: There's a blurry line between http://stackoverflow.com and http://unix.stackexchange.com. Shell scripting can be considered to be programming, but it can also be considered as specific to the Unix operating environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `.` doesn't mean 'current directory' in that context.  It's just shorthand for `source`.
2. sourcing a script (using `.` or `source`) runs the script in your *current* shell's context, rather than starting a subshell.  That means it can make modifications to your current shell's environment.  Simply running a script can't do that.  Example:

   ```
   $ cat script
   VARIABLE=something
   $ echo $VARIABLE

   $ ./script 
   $ echo $VARIABLE

   $ . ./script
   $ echo $VARIABLE
   something
   ```

Comment: The `CWD` (current working directory) is affected in much the same way.

Comment: I think what @JeremyJStarcher is getting at is that `cd` has to be a shell builtin and not an external executable for precisely the same reason.

Comment: I object: `source` is a long-hand for `.`!  The `.` command pre-dates the `source` command by a margin.  In the 'non C shell' family, `source` is quite a recent addition; it isn't in POSIX shell even now, though `.` is.  (_Please note:_ this is meant to be amusing/educational rather than a serious criticism of anything.)

Comment: @Carl What I was saying is that if you `cd` in a `source`d file, you end up at a different directory when the prompt comes back.  If a subshell changes directory, when it exits you are back at the same directory you started from.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - that's a good point, actually.  Trying to use `source` is probably less portable than the `.`.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason you might use "." or "source" to execute a script is if the script in question doesn't start with "#!/bin/bash" (the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)) which tells the shell which program should interpret the script in question.

Comment: But only if you want to run the script in your current shell's environment.  If you want to run it with a particular shell, you can just use `bash myscript` or `sh myscript` or `csh myscript`, etc.